# Error with MLCP copy syntax

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am using the following command

```
mlcp.sh copy -input_host localhost -output_host localhost \
-input_database emh-entity-manager-content \
-output_database emh-schema-map-manager-content \
-input_port 8000 -input_username admin -input_password xxxxxx \
-document_selector '/envelope[descendant::*:CustomerID = "SEVES"]'
```

And am getting the error

```
ERROR contentpump.ContentPump: Unrecognized argument: =
usage: COPY [-batch_size <number>] [-collection_filter <String>]
   [-copy_collections <true,false>] [-copy_permissions <true,false>]
   [-copy_properties <true,false>] [-copy_quality <true,false>]
   [-directory_filter <String>] [-document_selector <String>]
   [-fastload <true,false>] [-hadoop_conf_dir <directory>]
   [-input_database <database>] -input_host <host> [-input_password
   <password>] [-input_port <port>] [-input_username <username>]
   [-max_split_size <number>] [-min_split_size <number>] [-mode
   <mode>] [-output_collections <collections>] [-output_database
   <database>] [-output_directory <directory>] -output_host <host>
   [-output_partition <partition name>] [-output_password <password>]
   [-output_permissions <permissions>] [-output_port <port>]
   [-output_quality <quality>] [-output_uri_prefix <prefix>]
   [-output_uri_replace <list>] [-output_uri_suffix <suffix>]
   [-output_username <username>] [-path_namespace <String>]
   [-query_filter <String>] [-snapshot <true,false>]
   [-temporal_collection <String>] [-thread_count <count>]
   [-tolerate_errors <tolerate errors>] [-transaction_size <number>]
   [-transform_function <String>] [-transform_module <String>]
   [-transform_namespace <String>] [-transform_param <String>]
```

The error message is pretty much useless.  I am trying to copy a set of files that match a specific xpath from one database to another on the same server.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Loren

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on:

- You are missing the output_username
- You are missing the output_password
- You are running across some sort of command-line escaping issue.

MLCP has a nice option called **-options_file** that helps take care of the command line escaping. You simply add all options to a file and that gets parsed instead. https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/intro#id_36150

The command I would use is:

```
/path/to/mlcp.sh -options_file options.txt
```

With the content of the options.txt file being:

```
copy
-input_host
localhost
-output_host
localhost
-input_database
emh-entity-manager-content
-output_database
emh-schema-map-manager-content
-input_port
8000
-input_username
admin
-input_password
xxxxxx
-output_username
admin
-output_password
xxxxxx
-document_selector
/envelope[descendant::*:CustomerID = "SEVES"]
```

Comment: That is what I ended up doing and it worked.  Thanks